# Visual Format Language - padding area

Tags: cocoa, constraints, autolayout

I have several objects that are static in size that hug the top and bottom of the screen.  However, there is a blank area in the middle of the screen that I would like to stretch with orientation change.

I have solved an issue by adding an extra clear view [paddedView] that can be stretched but wanted to know if there was an easier way to do this without the paddedView just with Visual Format Language.

```
@"V:|-20-[topLabel(40)]-15-[anotherTopLabel(40)]-[paddedView]-[bottomView(73)]|";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a view used only for padding, you can either specify a lower priority to a distance or specify the constraint as "greater than or equal to".

Since what you want is a flexible space, the last option sounds like the best one:

```
@"V:|-20-[topLabel(40)]-15-[anotherTopLabel(40)]-(>=15)-[bottomView(73)]|"
```

The number `15` is of course just an example.